# Not able to add account in Outlook-2013

Tags: outlook, outlook-2010, outlook-2013, outlook-2016

I am not able to add an alternative account in my outlook-2013 it is giving the following error, can someone please help me to rectify the problem?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Select `Manually configure server setting` then click `next` and select `POP` or `IMAP` then click `next` [image]

In server information, give server mail in incoming server and outcome server (both must be same) like mail.co...whatever server you are using and In Account type select IPOP3, 
in Logon information type your user name and password, that was given to you when you had to make your account on web hosting control panel, when you give all the information then you will get an enabled button of More Setting..go there and go to advance tab and give data: [image]
then "OK" and next, make sure to test if the server works fine or not....its done!